# "You can call me Charlie. But do not call me late when there are scones about."

Tags: jokes

What is the joke in the following sentence from the Simpsons,season 17 episode 15.

> You can call me Charlie. But do not call me late when there are scones
>   about.

by Ricky Gervais, English comedian who produced and starred in The Office UK.

Comment: Typically scones is served at [(afternoon) tea](http://www.historic-uk.com/CultureUK/afternoon-tea/), it is a British tradition. Scones with clotted cream and strawberry jam is how they are often served. I suppose Charles doesn't want to be late for his tea.

Comment: It's a variation on an *old* joke:  "You can call me anything you want, just don't call me late for dinner."

Comment: @Mari-LouA For the avoidance of stereotyping can I just say that "Afternoon Tea" is no longer something *anyone* in the UK does in a traditional sense, other than when someone specifically wants to wallow in nostalgia. Asking to stop what you are doing in order to have afternoon tea is likely to be met with blank looks and perhaps stifled laughter in the UK, It has been this way for as long as I can remember (going back to the 70s). We do have the traditional "cream tea" which is what you describe, which is an old fashioned **seaside** (aka vacation) treat beloved only of nice old ladies.

Comment: I'm outraged. There are many fans of a proper 'cream tea', especially the Cornish variety, who are neither nice nor old. There are even some who aren't ladies.

Comment: @JHCL I suppose there will always be a few diehards :)

Answer (score 6):

It is a [zeugma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeugma), using "call" in two different senses.

Comment: Zeugma, that was the word I couldn't recall. :O