# Grammar Term for mistakenly using one verb for two expressions in one sentence

Tags: grammar

Sorry, I am having a hard time explaining this, so bear with me.

I am looking for a term describing incorrect grammar as in the following example:

> He drove the car and himself into a rage.

For the life of me, I just can't remember what it's called.

Comment: It's a zeugma. Or [syllepsis](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23592/of-the-difference-between-zeugma-and-syllepsis). Again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Cups of gold and wine"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/139599/cups-of-gold-and-wine). Though [You can call me Charlie, but do not call me late when there are scones about](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/273832/you-can-call-me-charlie-but-do-not-call-me-late-when-there-are-scones-about/273839#273839) is an example using a verb (and which can be blamed on Ricky Gervais).

Comment: Thanks, man. Yeah, it's the same thing as the other topic, I just couldn't think of the damn word and web searches all gave me unrelated things about compound verbs and such. Thank you!